# How can I prevent the \cfttoctitlefont command from the tocloft package from changing the font of the whole text?

Tags: tocloft

In my document, I use the `sectsty` package to change all chapter fonts from `huge` to `\LARGE`:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapterfont{\LARGE}
```

This works fine also for ToC, LoF, and LoT, as long as I do not use the `tocloft` pacakge. However, I also need to readjust the indents in those, so I inlcuded the `tocloft` package. After having included this package and changed the indents, all titles in ToC, LoF, and LoT are huge again. How can I change this?

I tried to use the `\cfttoctitlefont{\LARGE}` command. This does result in the title to be `\LARGE`, however, all other text in the remaining document is now `\LARGE` as well! How can I prevent the `\cfttoctitlefont` command from the tocloft package from changing the font of the whole text?

[image: Example of \LARGE text in ToC]

Answer (score 1):

If package `tocloft` should not change the settings of the headings in TOC etc. you can load it with option `titles`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\LARGE}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that `\cfttoctitlefont` does not take an argument. If you want to change the font of the TOC title using `\cfttoctitlefont` you have to *redefine* this command.

```
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\bfseries\LARGE}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\LARGE}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*\cfttoctitlefont{\bfseries\LARGE}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```